# How to format code?

Tags: support, code-formatting

How to format code on Stack Exchange sites? I have used <code> block with 8 spaces before and after each line but it does not recognize my code :S

Answer (score 0):

Paste the code into the "Your Answer" box, highlight it all and press the "Code Sample" button (5th from the left) or press `Control-K`